# find difference using UNION and minus

Tags: sql, union

I am bit out of my wits why the sql below would not produce any row. Clearly there is an id 1 which is not in b and I expected that to be the output. I know I am missing some fundamentals on how union works - may be due to the fact that there is not output in the second minus?

Redshift:

```
WITh a as 
(select 1 id union all select 2
)
,b as (select 2 id)
select * from a
minus
select * from b
union all 
select * from b
minus 
select * from a
```

Oracle-

```
WITh a as 
(select 1 id from dual union all select 2 from dual
)
,b as (select 2 id from dual)
select * from a
minus
select * from b
union all 
select * from b
minus 
select * from a
```

Comment: Please tell us which database you are using (e.g. SQL Server, Oracle, Postgres, etc.).

Comment: I checked both in Redshift and Oracle 12c.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an order of operations issue with the way you wrote your query.  If you wrap the two sides of the union as subqueries, and select from them, then you get the result you expect:

```
select * from
(select * from a
 minus
 select * from b ) t1
union all
select * from
(select * from b
 minus
 select * from a ) t2
```

What appears to be happening is that first the following is run, leaving us with `id=1`:

```
select * from a
minus
select * from b
```

Then, this result is being unioned with a query on `b`:

```
(select * from a
minus
select * from b)
union all
select * from b
```

At this point, the result set again has both 1 and 2 in it.  But now, we take a minus operation against table `a`:

```
(select * from a
minus
select * from b
union all 
select * from b)
minus 
select * from a
```

This results in an empty set, since `(1,2)` minus `(1,2)` leaves us with nothing.

Comment: @Fact It had to be something like this, otherwise it means `MINUS` is broken, which isn't very likely :-)

Comment: You are right on spot , union and minus have same precedence